# Standard and reliable mouse-reporting with GLUT

Tags: opengl, glut, mousewheel, freeglut

I'm trying to use GLUT (freeglut) in my OpenGL application, and I need to register some callbacks for mouse wheel events. I managed to dig out a fairly undocumented function:

[api documentation](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__input.html)

But the man page and the API entry for this function both state the same thing:

> Note: Due to lack of information about
>   the mouse, it is impossible to
>   implement this correctly on X at this
>   time. Use of this function limits the
>   portability of your application. (This
>   feature does work on X, just not
>   reliably.) You are encouraged to use
>   the standard, reliable mouse-button
>   reporting, rather than wheel events.

Fair enough, but how do I use this standard, reliable mouse-reporting? And how do I know which is the standard? Do I just use glutMouseFunc() and use button values like 4 and 5 for the scroll up and down values respectively, say if 1, 2 and 3 are the left, middle and right buttons? Is this the reliable method?

Bonus question: it seems the `xev' tool is reporting different values for my buttons. My mouse buttons are numbered from 1 to 5 with xev, but glut is reporting buttons from 0 to 4, i.e. an off-by-one. Is this common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I might revisit my own question since it has been a long time since I asked it without any replies.

Reading yet more thoroughly at aforementioned [documentation](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__input.html#ga6), from what I understand it seems that my guess was indeed true.

My guess:

> Do I just use `glutMouseFunc()` and use
>   button values like 4 and 5 for the
>   scroll up and down values respectively
>   [...]?

I haven't tested it yet, but from the following quote from the documentation, I gather that this is indeed what they meant.

> If you do not register a wheel
>   callback, wheel events will be
>   reported as mouse buttons.